# RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system during docker build

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia-docker, opennmt

I am trying to build a docker image that can use GPU for DeepLearning models. The problem is that I am getting this issue when trying to build the image

**RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx**

**process "python serializer.py config.yml" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1**

This is the content of my Dockerfile

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.0-base-ubuntu18.04
ENV FORCE_CUDA="0"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
RUN pip install torch==1.10.0+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
WORKDIR /home/server
COPY . /home/server/
RUN ["python","serializer.py","config.yml"]
```

Outside the docker builder, all works fine. It seems that when doing the docker builder the GPUs on the system are not beeing recognized.

Any help will be useful, thank you!

My main goal is creating a pickle version of a DeepLearning model, but I need to have access to a GPU when doing the docker builder in order to perform that.